Duplicate Item "Toggle Razor View" appearing on Visual Studio 2022 solution right click context menu
What is causing duplicate menu items in my Visual Studio 2022 Solution Explorer right click context menu?

The Visual Studio context menu has way too many items. On my screen it had a scrollbar because there was so many, so about a month ago I decided to remove most of them as I never use them. Since then I have noticed menu items duplicating themselves (as per above screenshot)
Has anyone seen his happen before? Any suggestions on what to do to fix it?
I have tried Tools> Customize> Commands> Context Menu> trying to find the duplicates here to remove them, but its like trying to find a needle in a haystack.
